# I have about 10,000 product list in my app. Is it normal for angular 2 and mongoose to have a delay of 2 seconds to display 18 per page?

Tags: mongodb, angular

When I am on my electronic site, my app finds about 6000. Each page has about 18 items. I can control how many items per page by setting the PRODUCT_PER_PAGE. This is my firs app in angular 2 and I am trying to built a large scale shopping cart. My app takes about 2 seconds to display 18 pages. Is this normal? By the way, below is the my code select a page. Thanks in advance.

```
onSelectPage(thePage: string) {
    //page(1/4) /*
/*  var slash = Number(page.indexOf('/'));
    var length = slash - 5;
    page = page.substr(5, length); */

    let page = Number(thePage);

    let productDisplay = this._searchProductService.products;
    this.products = [];
    this.productsNextColumn = [];       
    let pageNumber = Number(page) - 1;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.pageDisplay = pageNumber + 1;

    if(this.isClicked) {
        productDisplay = this.theClickedQueries;
        if(productDisplay.length > 0)
            productDisplay = this.theClickedQueries;
        else
            productDisplay = this._searchProductService.products;
    }
    let productDisplayLength = productDisplay.length;

    if(this.pageNumber == 0) {
        this.startDisplay = 0;
        this.endDisplay = this.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE/2;
        this.previousPage = 'disabled';
        for(let i=this.startDisplay; i <this.endDisplay; i++) {
            this.products.push(productDisplay[i]);
        }
        let nextColumn = this.endDisplay + this.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE/2;
        for(let i=this.endDisplay; i<nextColumn; i++){
            this.productsNextColumn.push(productDisplay[i]);
        }   
    }
    //Click on other pages..
    else {
        this.previousPage = '';
        this.startDisplay = this.pageNumber * this.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE;

        this.endDisplay = this.startDisplay + this.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE/2;
        if(productDisplayLength > this.endDisplay) {
            for(let i=this.startDisplay; i <this.endDisplay; i++) 
                this.products.push(productDisplay[i]);
            let nextColumn = this.endDisplay + this.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE/2; 
            if(productDisplayLength >= nextColumn) {
                for(let i=this.endDisplay; i<nextColumn; i++)
                    this.productsNextColumn.push(productDisplay[i]);
                if(productDisplayLength > nextColumn)
                    this.nextPage = '';
                else
                    this.nextPage = 'disabled';
            } else {
                for(let i=this.endDisplay; i<productDisplayLength; i++){
                    this.productsNextColumn.push(productDisplay[i]);
                }
                this.nextPage = 'disabled';             
            }
        } else {
            for(let i=this.startDisplay; i <productDisplayLength; i++) 
                this.products.push(productDisplay[i]);  
        }
    }
    if(this.advertisements[this.pageNumber] != null) 
        this.advertisement = this.advertisements[this.pageNumber];              
}
```

Comment: have you checked your data payload? you sure the problem is in angular?

Comment: When I reduce my items to about 1000, I see only less than a second delay.

Comment: how large is the data you are transferring?

Comment: I made up my data with mongoose dB. To be honest with you, I am tired making up items on my product seed. I actually made up 300 items in electronics, 50 in video games, 20 in toys. So I ran "node product-seed.js" many times to have many items in my product list.

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. I appreciate your time. And If I wasted your time because of your down vote, you have a nice day.

Comment: @harold_mean2, don't care much about the downvote. Please, be more specific in your question. We're here to help you.

Comment: I do not know how long to display 18 items per page to search about 10,000 items. And like on my question, this is my first A2 app using mongo DB. As you can see, when I search for electronics, my app searched about 6000, items, but I am only displaying 18 items per page.

Comment: It's hard to tell what "18 pages" means exactly. Usually it's a good practice to not add large amount of markup to the DOM if the users doesn't actually see it. There is for example virtual scrolling, that prevents adding lots of elements to the DOM that are hidden and can only made visible by scrolling. The same for tabs, where hidden tabs are not actually hidden, but remove from the DOM. Also there should be no need to load thousands of items from the server, but just fetching about 100 and while they are shown loading more.

Comment: I go to live shopping retailer store and they are able to search 6000 items but yet display only about 20 items telling their customers they have 6000 in that categories. Once, I search the 6000 items, clicking an apple brand about 200 products, the 18 items appear right away(no delay at all) because while I am searching the items I am also storing them in an array. For example, If I search electronics, there are 300 apple products, 100 google products, motorola 50, etc.

Comment: @harold_mean2 from your last comment it seems you are making the assumption that "live shopping retailer stores" loads all 6000 items into the client application without delay. This almost certainly not the case. One application design pattern that many data driven applications use is server side pagination. Basically the server sends a subset  of data to the client AKA a "page", and the client requests for additional pages when needed. Here is an angularJS example using server side pagination https://ciphertrick.com/2015/08/31/server-side-pagination-in-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer I am looking for. Thanks for the link. You have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

One application design pattern that many data driven applications use is server side pagination. Basically the server sends a subset of data to the client AKA a "page", and the client requests for additional pages when needed. Here is an angularJS example using server side pagination https://ciphertrick.com/2015/08/31/server-side-pagination-in-angularjs